# Continuous controller to ternary switch

Tags: circuit-design

I have to create an adapter that will take a pot(it is a piano pedal) to 3 states, full, half, and off. That is, the piano only supports what is called half-damper and not continuous control so I have to modify the pedal so it works. The issue is I do not want to have to supply a battery nor design a complex circuit.

Here is the specs:

The paino has 3 inputs, F, H, and Gnd. F and H are pulled up to 3.3V by 10k. The pot on the pedal is 10k but only ranges from 9k to 2k. I replaced the pot so it goes from 135k to 93k. Clearly half way between these ranges is the half damper setting.

Normally the pedal would simply act as a voltage divider and the piano would read the voltage from 0 to V and that would correspond to the damper value. In this case F must "float" and H is grounded gives half damper. For full dampening F and H must be grounded. When F and H are floating no dampening takes place.

Hence this is just converting the high resistance to F = H = 1, the in between to F = 1, H = 0, and the low resistance to F = H = 0. Clearly though the pot can be reversed(and ideally a simple switch can do this because sometimes the effects are different).

I feel that there is some way to rig up a simple circuit so it works but since the pots do not go all the way to 0 and the pullup resistors are so high it seems to make it difficult. I can't really change the pot range as the actuator arm mechanics is fixed.

It doesn't have to be perfect although I think some hysteresis like effect would be required because unlike a real piano you can't "recover" the dampening. This means that if you enter H or F mode and then back off quickly then renter you get nothing. Hence any jitter around these values could cause problems. I'm not sure how the piano handles it though. It doesn't have to be all that robust beyond these issues. As long as it works then it works.

Although I guess I could try to modify the pullups to provide more drive.... that might be the way to go but might cause problems with the uC. I might be able to add a VCC pin that gives more drive directly too so two comparators could be run. I'd ideally like to just use a few transistors though.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the the proper accessory do? Have a pot or something else

Comment: there doesn't seem to bne much energy available to power the comparator. What are the voltage thresholds for high and low.

Comment: Does grounding either F or H produce half damper. Or just F for Full? and H for Half? Or as you said ... both for Full.???

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Grounding H and leaving F alone("floating"/pulled up) will do half damper. Doing this for F will not, you have to also ground H. The reason is because the foot pedal will depress H then all the way down will depress H and F. I do not know the thresholds. It is going directly in to an IC so I imagine the typical thresholds for cmos. The pedal uses a pot. The pedal simply controls/rotates the pot about 30 degrees. I cannot set the range at which it does this on the pot though, hence the values I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3pReC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit essentially works. Each resistor can be set to modify the differential voltage between the signal VCC's and they can also be used to set the offsets.

It is essentially a balancing bridge. In my case all the variable resistors are 10k which match the pullup's on VCC and the pot. I use the pot only as a variable resistor. The threshold voltage is 1.4V so I only have to tweak the resistors so that the two thresholds are properly set.

It might take a bit more variable resistors to get the precise ranges(some non-linear scaling so it fits within the desired window) but the idea should work generally.

Update: This works quite well for my scenario. I used 10k trim pots for all the varistors and was able to eliminate 2 completely. Just happened to work out well in my case for some reason without much tweaking.

Comment: It's not clear what's going on here. Right-click the resistors and use the variable resistor symbol if required. Use the pot symbol if you're using it as a potentiometer.

Comment: @Transistor If you don't know what is going on then you have more problems than the diagram.

Comment: Are you trying to be funny or rude?

Comment: @Transistor Neither, just being honest.

Answer (score 0):

replace the pot with a 3 throw rotary switch.everything then becomes much simpler.

or you could try rthis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBIts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
you'll need to adjust your pot's mounting so that the resistance can go down to zero and up to at-least 40K. it might need two diodes in series.

Comment: Not at all. I would have to find a rotary switch that had the exact turn ratio that the device uses. It would also add subtle clicks to the pedal which probably would be awkwardly felt... and it might cause issues with the signal is there is any gap between changes.

Comment: 1:  true most switches work in 30 degree steps. 2: if they are problematic the spring can be removed. 3: use a shorting switch instead of non-shorting.

Comment: I wonder if 10k pot and bias resistors can make 2 JFETs conduct at different resistor levels to get IDSS near 0V across each JFET (Pch) to simulate pull down of each at different thresholds of a single R:xR ratios

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 That was my initial approach. It's harder to work out though because one has to balance them just right. It might not work in practice well because of jitter which caps may or may not help with.  The issue is because there is no independent power supply. I really don't want to have to replace a battery ever month(if lucky) and it is a bit of work to try to run a power supply through the setup. I was hoping someone would have a setup that would work or at least theoretically work that I could then tinker with if needed.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The whole point of using fets and mosfets is because it should work well with the power requirements... but the problem is that the "transition" levels are generally ~100mV or so. It would not be a major issue if I could get the pot to swing it's full range but unfortunately it's a rather cheaply made(but expensive) pedal.  Also, a battery would generally cause drift which would cause problems.

Comment: FETs won't work without a power supply. which we're not allowed...

Comment: No, there is power, the problem is not that there isn't power but that the power comes from the very line that one is trying to control and it has high impedance. This means the circuit is non-linear and requires someone with intelligence to design it. It is not difficult to get a very rough approximation that works, the hard part is getting a design that actually works in circuit due to the specific resistances and threshold voltages.